# Is any submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the zero set of some polynomial?

Tags: geometry

For a given circle we have a corresponding equation to generate it. For a given ellipsoid we also can write a corresponding equation for it. In general, can we write for any given manifold an equation to characterize it? I googled this but I did not get useful information.

Comment: Are you referring to a metric?

Comment: Sorry? What does it mean by "referring to a metric"?  @Doryan Miller

Comment: To be precise, are you asking whether any submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ is the zero set of some polynomial? Elementary function? Smooth function?

Comment: Ah yes. Is any submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the zero set of some polynomial?

Comment: @Brian Polynomials are not enough. For example, the sine curve on a plane is not the zero set of any polynomial (reason: it intersects real line infinitely often). Zero set of a smooth function: yes, but this means less than you might imagine. It's a theorem of Whitney that every closed set is the zero set of some smooth function.

Comment: Disregard my comment. The edits clarified what you're asking.

Comment: @Thursday: Thank you. I am not sure, do you mean that any Euclidean submanifold is the zero set of a smooth function? Is there a theorem for this?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [algebraic manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_manifold).

Comment: @Thursday: Is that really the reason? Isn't the entire real line in the zero set of the polynomial $f(x,y)=xy$?

Comment: @MPW You can have the entire line, but you can't have an infinite proper subset thereof. The restriction of polynomial to a line is either identically zero, or has finitely many zeros.

Comment: @Thursday: Interesting, I did not know that. +1, then.

Comment: Is the open unit disk a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, certainly not.  Consider the curve $\{ (x,y): y = e^x \}$.  This is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it is not the zero set of a polynomial equation.

Comment: What's the proof that it's not?

Comment: Because there is no polynomial function that produces the same graph as an exponential function.

Comment: Unconvinced. The curve $y=1/(1+x^2)$ is not the graph of any polynomial, but it's the zero set of $p(x,y)=x^2y+y-1$.

Comment: Hmm.  Excellent point.  What's the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}[x]$?